# Input to reshape is a tensor with 984064 values, but the requested shape requires a multiple of 1568

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I'm training a model to predict whether an eye in a picture is open or closed. I have this code, but I'm getting the error

> Input to reshape is a tensor with 984064 values, but the requested
> shape requires a multiple of 1568.

Here is my code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1./255,
    shear_range=0.2,
    zoom_range=0.2,
    horizontal_flip=True
)

training_set = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    'C:/Users/shtey/OneDrive/Desktop/Datasets/Eye Detection/dataset/train',
    target_size=(64, 64),
    batch_size=32, 
    class_mode='binary'
)

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
test_set = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    'C:/Users/shtey/OneDrive/Desktop/Datasets/Eye Detection/dataset/test'
)

cnn = tf.keras.models.Sequential()

cnn.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=8, kernel_size=3, activation='relu', input_shape=[64, 64, 3]))
cnn.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=2, strides=2))

cnn.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=8, kernel_size=3, activation='relu'))
cnn.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=2, strides=2))

cnn.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten())

cnn.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=8, activation='relu'))
cnn.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=1, activation='sigmoid'))

cnn.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

cnn.fit(x=training_set, validation_data=test_set, epochs = 20)
```

Here is the error:

```
InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [18], in <cell line: 3>()
      1 cnn.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
----> 3 cnn.fit(x=training_set, validation_data=test_set, epochs = 20)

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py:67, in filter_traceback.<locals>.error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
     65 except Exception as e:  # pylint: disable=broad-except
     66   filtered_tb = _process_traceback_frames(e.__traceback__)
---> 67   raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
     68 finally:
     69   del filtered_tb

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\execute.py:54, in quick_execute(op_name, num_outputs, inputs, attrs, ctx, name)
     52 try:
     53   ctx.ensure_initialized()
---> 54   tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
     55                                       inputs, attrs, num_outputs)
     56 except core._NotOkStatusException as e:
     57   if name is not None:

InvalidArgumentError: Graph execution error:

Detected at node 'sequential_5/flatten_4/Reshape' defined at (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\shtey\anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 197, in _run_module_as_main
      return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
    File "C:\Users\shtey\anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
      exec(code, run_globals)
    File "C:\Users\shtey\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel_launcher.py", line 16, in <module>
      app.launch_new_instance()
    File "C:\Users\shtey\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\traitlets\config\application.py", line 846, in launch_instance
      app.start()
    File "C:\Users\shtey\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelapp.py", line 677, in start
      self.io_loop.start()
    File "C:\Users\shtey\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\platform\asyncio.py", line 199, in start
      self.asyncio_loop.run_forever()
    File "C:\Users\shtey\anaconda3\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 601, in run_forever
      self._run_once()
    File "C:\Users\shtey\anaconda3\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 1905, in _run_once
      handle._run()
    File "C:\Users\shtey\anaconda3\lib\asyncio\events.py", line 80, in _run
      self._context.run(self._callback, *self._args)
    File "C:\Users\shtey\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelbase.py", line 471, in dispatch_queue
      await self.process_one()
    File "C:\Users\shtey\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelbase.py", line 460, in process_one
      await dispatch(*args)
    File "C:\Users\shtey\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelbase.py", line 367, in dispatch_shell
      await result
    File "C:\Users\shtey\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelbase.py", line 662, in execute_request
      reply_content = await reply_content
    File "C:\Users\shtey\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\ipkernel.py", line 360, in do_execute
      res = shell.run_cell(code, store_history=store_history, silent=silent)
    File "C:\Users\shtey\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\zmqshell.py", line 532, in run_cell
      return super().run_cell(*args, **kwargs)
    File "C:\Users\shtey\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2863, in run_cell
      result = self._run_cell(
    File "C:\Users\shtey\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2909, in _run_cell
      return runner(coro)
    File "C:\Users\shtey\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\async_helpers.py", line 129, in _pseudo_sync_runner
      coro.send(None)
    File "C:\Users\shtey\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3106, in run_cell_async
      has_raised = await self.run_ast_nodes(code_ast.body, cell_name,
    File "C:\Users\shtey\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3309, in run_ast_nodes
      if await self.run_code(code, result, async_=asy):
    File "C:\Users\shtey\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3369, in run_code
      exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
    File "C:\Users\shtey\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_4224\2238439442.py", line 3, in <cell line: 3>
      cnn.fit(x=training_set, validation_data=test_set, epochs = 20)
    File "C:\Users\shtey\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 64, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "C:\Users\shtey\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1445, in fit
      val_logs = self.evaluate(
    File "C:\Users\shtey\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 64, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "C:\Users\shtey\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1756, in evaluate
      tmp_logs = self.test_function(iterator)
    File "C:\Users\shtey\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1557, in test_function
      return step_function(self, iterator)
    File "C:\Users\shtey\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1546, in step_function
      outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    File "C:\Users\shtey\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1535, in run_step
      outputs = model.test_step(data)
    File "C:\Users\shtey\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1499, in test_step
      y_pred = self(x, training=False)
    File "C:\Users\shtey\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 64, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "C:\Users\shtey\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 490, in __call__
      return super().__call__(*args, **kwargs)
    File "C:\Users\shtey\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 64, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "C:\Users\shtey\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\base_layer.py", line 1014, in __call__
      outputs = call_fn(inputs, *args, **kwargs)
    File "C:\Users\shtey\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 92, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "C:\Users\shtey\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\sequential.py", line 374, in call
      return super(Sequential, self).call(inputs, training=training, mask=mask)
    File "C:\Users\shtey\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\functional.py", line 458, in call
      return self._run_internal_graph(
    File "C:\Users\shtey\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\functional.py", line 596, in _run_internal_graph
      outputs = node.layer(*args, **kwargs)
    File "C:\Users\shtey\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 64, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "C:\Users\shtey\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\base_layer.py", line 1014, in __call__
      outputs = call_fn(inputs, *args, **kwargs)
    File "C:\Users\shtey\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 92, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "C:\Users\shtey\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\layers\reshaping\flatten.py", line 98, in call
      return tf.reshape(inputs, flattened_shape)
Node: 'sequential_5/flatten_4/Reshape'
Input to reshape is a tensor with 984064 values, but the requested shape requires a multiple of 1568
     [[{{node sequential_5/flatten_4/Reshape}}]] [Op:__inference_test_function_6158]
```

I've searched around but I can't seem to find the fix.

Comment: Have you tried giving the same target size to your test set?

Answer (score 0):

(As mentioned by **@zousan**) You must provide the same `target_size` for the validation dataset as the training dataset which should match with the `input_shape` of the model definition and if you are using this `test_set` as validation dataset in model training.

Actually, pre-processing attributes should be the same for both the datasets to avoid causing the error.

**Training dataset:**

```
training_set = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    'C:/Users/shtey/OneDrive/Desktop/Datasets/Eye Detection/dataset/train',
    target_size=(64, 64),
    batch_size=32, 
    class_mode='binary')
```

**Validation dataset:**

```
test_set = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    'C:/Users/shtey/OneDrive/Desktop/Datasets/Eye Detection/dataset/test'
        target_size=(64, 64),
        batch_size=32, 
        class_mode='binary')
```

Please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70054915/14290681) similar issue for your reference.